# JScrollPane automagically scrolls down to lowest component in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

In my JPanel (which is in a JScrollPane) I have several JTextArea. When launching the program these areas are populated by JTextArea.setText("text");

The problem is that the JScrollPane scrolls down to the JTextArea with the lowest Y-position as if the user would have focus on the JTextArea, no matter when it was populated with text. I thought that I could work around the problem by populating the JTextArea at the bottom first, if the JScrollPane maybe want to scroll to the "current" JTextArea that's being used. It didn't work so I'm assuming it just remembers the lowest point it's been and then just stays there for some reason.

Setting the view like this doesn't make any difference.

```
JScrollPane.getViewPort().scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(0,0,1,1));
```

I've tested by neglecting to populate the last JTextAreas and the JScrollPane is then viewing the top of the JPanel, as I want.
What's happening, and why is it ignoring my code?

***Update, answer selected***
You have to set the viewport a tad later when the GUI is ready

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            scrollPane.getViewport().setViewPosition(new Point(0, 0));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please post a runnable [mcve], I don't get the same result when I try to reproduce this problem.

Comment: I'm unable to do that I'm afraid. The project is quite large and can't easily be stripped down and I'd rather not post everything on here :P no one would actually take the time to go through everything anyway...

Comment: @XistenZ, `I'm unable to do that I'm afraid.` - for the future, you were not asked for your project. Your problem is a panel with multiple text areas. So you can easily create a JFrame, containing a JScrollPane, containing a panel with multiple text areas. This is sufficient to demonstrate the problem. The point of an MCVE is to highlight the problem, not the project. Many times when you create the MCVE you will solve the problem as you simplify the problem.

Comment: I know, what I should've rephrased and said "I'm unable to reproduce the problem". As I created a JFrame, JScrollPane and multiple JTextAreas and the problem was not reproduced. That being the case, the problem is apparently hidden somewhere in my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JScrollPane.getViewPort().scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(0,0,1,1));
```

The scrollRectToVisible() method is meant to be used on the component added to the viewport (the panel containing the text areas), not the viewport itself. Not sure what happens when you invoke it directly on the viewport.

Instead I would do the following:

```
scrollPane.getViewPort().setViewPosition( new Point(0, 0) );
```

Note, you may need to wrap that statement in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater() to make sure the code is executed on the EDT after all the components have been positioned on the panel by the layout manager.

Comment: Adding that line in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater() did the trick! I'm editing my question with the code, since you can't format in comments. Thanks!